# HTTPService: What is its send method doing?

Tags: actionscript-3

I've got a JSON string:

```
query = {"action":"do","password":"c","name":"s"}
```

When using HTTPService's send method:

```
_service = new HTTPService();
_service.url = "http://localhost:8080";
_service.method = "POST";
_service.contentType = "application/json";
_service.resultFormat = "text";
_service.useProxy = false;
_service.makeObjectsBindable = true;
_service.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT,faultRX);
_service.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT,resultRX);
_service.showBusyCursor = true;
var _request:Object = new Object();
_request.query = query;
_service.request = _request;
_service.send();
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong but on my HTTP server I get:

```
{["object","Object"]}
```

Any clues please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring an object of an object.

Try:

```
_service.request = query;
_service.send();
```

Comment: This works great. What would you do if you where to upload a file as well?

Answer (score 0):

you get

```
{["object","Object"]}
```

because of this

```
var _request:Object = new Object();
_request.query = query;
_service.request = _request;
```

do this

```
 var jsonOBJ:Object = {};
     jsonOBJ.action = "do";
     jsonOBJ.password = "c";
     jsonOBJ.name = "s";

var _service:HTTPService = new HTTPService();
    _service.url = "http://localhost:8080";
    _service.method = "POST";
    _service.contentType = "application/json";
    _service.resultFormat = "text";
    _service.useProxy = false;
    _service.makeObjectsBindable = true;
    _service.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT,faultRX);
    _service.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT,resultRX);
    _service.showBusyCursor = true;
    _service.send( JSON.encode( jsonOBJ ) );// encode the json object with AS3Corelib
```

Don't forget top JSON decode the string on the server side.